# Feynman rule with complex coupling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, complex-numbers, interactions

Suppose I have 3 complex scalar fields and an interaction term

$$ \mathcal{L}\supset -g \chi \phi_1 \phi_2 + {\rm h.c.} $$

where $g$ is a complex constant whose phase I cannot get rid of by field rotation.

The first term could represent a $\chi$ particle decaying into "anti-"$\phi_1$ and "anti-"$\phi_2$ particles. The Feynman rule for this vertex is simply $-ig$.

What about the conjugate term? The $\chi^\dagger \phi_1^\dagger\phi_2^\dagger$ interaction represents an "anti-"$\chi$ decaying into $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ particles. What is the Feynman rule then? Is it $-ig^*$ or $(-ig)^* = +ig^*$? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I usually work in the convention that if $L$ includes $g\chi \phi_1  \phi_2$, then each vertex carries a factor of $(-ig)$. Similarly, if $L$ includes its Hermitian conjugate $g^*\phi_2^\dagger \phi_1^\dagger \chi^\dagger$, then each vertex carries a factor of $(-ig^*)$. This is for momentum space Feynman rules.

However, note that there are different Feynman rules with different conventions which get the same results. A full description of what you are doing would be needed to confirm what you need to do.

Comment: This probably makes sense since we are expanding the action $e^{iS}$ in series, so to leading order every term in the Lagrangian is just multiplied by $i$.
I am interested in computing the self-energy diagram of two states $\chi_1$, $\chi_2$ which are mixing via a $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ loop. This is proportional to $g_1 g^*_2$, but I wanted to get the sign right.